# unable to retrieve images from storage folder - path from database

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and I wish to upload images and place the path into database, it's easy and I did it, all is cool. now trying to retrieve the image, the path is correct and I tried to change the settings of the folders and the storage, I tried to find every single solution out there for 7 hours and still i can't find the issue, please advise.

I tried to change the storage from local to public and tried to use different methods to recall the image but all failed.

```
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('storage/'.$post->background_image) }}">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="/storage//{{$post['first_image']}}" alt="Card image cap">

        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{$post['post_name']}}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{$post['description']}}</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 2</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

//as for saving the file i tried the below options:

```
$path1 = $request->file('background_image')->store('background_image');

if ($validatedImages) {

$fileNamewithExt= $request->file('background_image')
                          ->getClientOriginalName();

$filename= pathinfo($fileNamewithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = $request ->file('background_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
$path1 = $request->file('background_image')
                   ->storeAs('/background_image',$fileNameToStore);
 }
```

I expect the image to load instead of appearing unavailable, the path loads from the database, but for some reason the image doesn't load.

Comment: What is the final path formed and have you checked that image exists on that path?

Comment: Did you `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: yes, the image exists and yes storage is linked; the full path from the HTML page: http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/background_image/uTJL1Q6nIS27nalgHmoaPnjDsjDmGh1Afnu5vFiZ.jpeg so it was loaded successfully from the DB

Comment: On the third line `<img class="card-img-top" src="/storage//{{$post['first_image']}}" alt="Card image cap">` after the storage you have double `//` ?

Comment: Juan, it's added by mistake, it's one hash in the original code. I'm afraid that's not it.

Comment: In your project, do you see the file saved in <Project-Root>/storage/app/public folder ? This is the location which gets linked to the <Project-Root>/public/storage folder. And if you changed your .env from local to public, make sure you do php artisan config:clear for env changes to take effect. The filesystems should have public for files to be accessed publicly